# Streaming Insert API throttling

Tags: google-bigquery

We are evaluating BigQuery and as part of that we try streaming insert API.
We are reading from kafka queue and push the received data using streaming insert api.

The google docs say api throttling limit is 10 request per second

My questions are :

1. Is the limit applicable to per table?i.e. If we insert to 15 different tables per second will it be throttled?
2. Is the limit applicable to per project? If yes, if we read and insert simultaneously then my understanding is reading api rate would be 1/sec and same for insert api. Is it correct?
3. Is there any restrictions on number of tables?
4. Is there any restrictions on number of datasets?
5. Also once throttled, after how much time the throttling ban limit will be withdrawn?

Thanks,
Sourav

Answer (score 0):

1. Maximum rows per second: 10,000 rows per second, per table
2. You can find out more limits there: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy
3. and 4. I don't know any such limits